# How to use Java Arrays -- Translating From Ruby to Java

Tags: java, ruby, arrays

I'm just starting with Java, so I'm transcribing some of my Ruby stuff. I have a Ruby function like this, which generates something that looks like an IPv6 address:

```
def generate_ip()
    list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    address = ""
    8.times do
        4.times do
            address << list.shuffle[5]
        end
        address << ":"
    end
    return address[0..-2].to_sym
end
```

This method simply takes an array of strings and then repeatedly jumbles them up, choosing the 5th element each time to construct the returned string.

As far as I can tell, there's no "shuffle()" method for String Arrays in Java, so I figured I'd write my own. But then I started to get completely mired in sub-problems, such as:

1. Apparently there's no built-in way to remove items from a String Array, which seems strange -- is that correct? I saw several other SO posts where the responses for this features were a 10-line block of code. So I decided to use ArrayLists, since according to the doc, they have sane methods like size(), get(), and remove(), although...
2. ...I haven't found a way to instantiate them using a literal, or to add multiple items with a single method call. Every tutorial I see (including the official Oracle Java Tutorial) uses multiple calls to ArrayList.add(). That can't be the way to do it, can it?
3. etc.

So before I go spiraling down into sub-problem land and asking 50 different questions, I thought I'd ask how to solve the most important problem. Is there a simple way to translate the above Ruby code into Java?

FWIW, my in-progress "shuffle" method is below. I'm just looping array.length times, copying/removing a random element from the old array to a new array each time.

```
public ArrayList<String> shuffle(ArrayList<String> array) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> shuffled = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i > array.size(); i++) {
            int index = generator.nextInt(array.size());

            String popped = array.get(index);
            array.remove(index);

            shuffled.add(popped);
        }


        return shuffled;
    }
```

Comment: Before doing a 1-to-1 translation, consider a more idiomatic Ruby version of the method body: `Array.new(8) { "%04x" % rand(2**16) }.join(':').chop.to_sym`

Comment: Lars, woah! Thanks for this, it's SLICK! (although why the .chop ?)

Comment: `str.chop` is the same thing as `str[0..-2]` (in the last line of your method), but more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a `List` (either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`), you can use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

ArrayList and LinkedList are both implementations of the List interface. I suspect either would be ok for your needs here, although the ArrayList would be preferable (being backed by an array). Here's the [Java List tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Arrays are of a fixed length in Java, whereas a `List` is variable in size, and so the `List` is more appropriate in general for your above conversion. To create a list with a given set of starting elements, see [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) e.g.

```
List stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Collections.shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) built-in library available in java.

> Randomly permute the specified list using the specified source of randomness. All permutations occur with equal likelihood assuming that the source of randomness is fair.

[open jdk code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List,java.util.Random%29).